# DAX: Using Measure as a slicer and count total

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table where it shown the items and its frequency.

```
+---------+-------+
| ITEMS   | FREQ  |
+---------+-------+
| apple   |     7 |
| banana  |     5 |
| carrot  |     8 |
| potato  |     8 |
+---------+-------+
```

Frequency is obtained by using DAX measure.

```
Frequency = CALCULATE(COUNT('Tbl1'[Item]), NOT('Tbl1'[Item Status]) IN {"BAD"})
```

I want to create a card visual that depending on the chosen frequency, will show the total number of items. For example Freq 7 = 1, Freq 8 =2. I tried to use `Frequency` as a slicer, but its not working. Is there any ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate table to use as a frequency slicer.

Define a new calculated table with no relationships to other table:

```
Frequencies =
VAR MaxFreq = MAXX ( ALL ( Tbl1[Item] ), [Frequency] )
RETURN
    GENERATESERIES ( 0, MaxFreq )
```

You can then use the column `Frequencies[Value]` as a slicer and define a new measure to count the number of items with frequency matching the frequency selected via this slicer as:

```
FreqCount =
VAR Freq = SELECTEDVALUE ( Frequencies[Value] )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( VALUES ( Tbl1[Item] ), [Frequency] = Freq ) )
```