# Powerbi Measure in X axis has numerical value and change slicer by measure value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working on the problem statement where I need to use a measure in X axis. Data looks like below.

[image]

Measure I wanted to used in x axis bar chart:

```
Epic_Touched = 
Var Epic_cnt = sum(Sprint_epic_init_sub_init[NUMBER_OF_EPICS_TOUCHED_PER_SPRINT])
Var Sprint_cnt = calculate(DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(Sprint_epic_init_sub_init[SPRINT_ID]))

Var div = DIVIDE(Epic_cnt,Sprint_cnt)
VAR res = IFERROR(div,0)
return if(res=BLANK(),0)
```

The above measure returns this result in a table format.

[image]

**I basically wanted to use this measure in the bar chart x axis that will be 5,8,10 and y axis to show how times measure values occurred that will be 3,1,1 respectively.
And need a slicer in the measure value to change the values accordingly,  Can you advise me on how to achieve it?**

I have tried below virtual table and measure to achieve it, but unable to do that.

This measure returns table that shows the project_key, end date and corresponding epic touched count details.

```
Epic_measure_filter_table = 

ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            Sprint_epic_init_sub_init,
            Sprint_epic_init_sub_init[PROJECT_KEY],
            Sprint_epic_init_sub_init[SPRINT_END_TS]
        ),
        "Epic_Cnt",[Epic_Touched]
)
```

This measure will be used to slice the data by the data user selected.

```
epic_cnt_filter = 
VAR minvalue  = min(Epic_measure_filter_table[Epic_Cnt])
VAR maxvalue = max(Epic_measure_filter_table[Epic_Cnt])
VAR curr_measure_value = [Epic_Touched]

return
if(
    curr_measure_value>=minvalue && curr_measure_value <=maxvalue ,
    1,0
 )
```

But above measure are not working, can you advise me on this problem statement?

**New Measure tried:**

**Below measure created the virtual table.**

```
Epic = 
Var max_epic = MAXX(all(Sprint_epic_init_sub_init[PROJECT_KEY]),[Epic_Touched])
return 
GENERATESERIES(0,max_epic)
```

Measure used to count the value selected. But its not working as expected. I'm using date filter as well to select the data range, I think its affecting the result.

```
Cnt = 
Var sel_val = SELECTEDVALUE(Epic[Value])
return 
COUNTROWS(FILTER(VALUES(Sprint_epic_init_sub_init[PROJECT_KEY]),[Epic_Touched]=sel_val))
```

Below is the result for reference.

[image]

**2nd approach, Measure with Parameter**:

```
new_epic_mes = 

CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sprint_epic_init_sub_init[PROJECT_KEY]),
FILTER(Sprint_epic_init_sub_init, [Epic_Touched] in VALUES( Parameter[Parameter])))
```

I need to average the parameter value for each project key and count it accordingly and use the avg parameter value in x axis, You can see the output in the below image for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68617417/dax-using-measure-as-a-slicer-and-count-total/68624211 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956190/how-to-use-a-measure-as-an-axis-in-power-bi

Comment: @AlexisOlson, I have created the virtual table and countrows measure but countrows are not returns the correct answer , can you help me on this. I have edited the question and updated with new virtual table and measure for reference. Can you help me to fix this.

Comment: @AlexisOlson, I have used the CALCULATE measure and parameter slicer to get the results but x axis value not averaging as it is a paramerter. Can you help me on this. I have updated the result for your reference.